# How Do I configure lookup column as a hyperlink in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lookup

I do not have access to SPD.
I only have access to creating lists and libraries from the site settings menu
My requirement is to 
1. Create folders under a document library - Acheived
2.Create a list with columns
 a. Name
 b. folder name
 c. primary contact

of the above folder naem should be looking up to the Document Library
when A User clicks on the folder name, it should redirect to the respective folder.

My Problem : Clicking the folder name opens a pop up window with options to edit the item
instead of redirecting the user to the folder

Answer (score 0):

I setup this up the same way in SharePoint 2013. Upon clicking on the folder name in the list it opened the dialog box with options to edit the item which is By Design. But, I also had an option on the Ribbon Bar in the dialog box to "Open" the folder directly.

There might be a way to create a Hyperlink column in the list and create a workflow to update the column with the actual URL of the folder location which would resolve your issue but since  you do not have access to SharePoint Designer this will not be an option.

-JasonR